# Rails - how to redirect from www.website.com to website.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I would like to redirect all requests, that coming to `www.website.com/whatever` to the variant without `www`.
How to do this in Rails & what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for this. If you want to do it within rails the following gem might be useful

https://github.com/iSabanin/www_ditcher

However, such tasks are generally configured from the app server. Please look at this question previously posted on stack overflow

[301 redirect in Passenger (Ruby on Rails) from root domain to www sub domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925068/301-redirect-in-passenger-ruby-on-rails-from-root-domain-to-www-sub-domain)

It does the complement of what you seek to do, however it should get you on track. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's best to keep the logic for that completely our of your Rails app and rather take care of it in the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

gem 'rack-www' works nicely for this.

https://github.com/stjhimy/rack-www