# Lost httpd.conf file located apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

How can I find where my `httpd.conf` file is located?

I am running an Ubuntu Linux server from the Amazon Web Services EC2 (Elastic Compute Cloud) and I can't find my Apache config.

Comment: Which OS are you using? How did you install Apache? Which version of Apache are you running? These are all things that you should include when this gets moved the correct place (probably SeverFault).

Comment: Linux Ubuntu. I installed Apache by getting httpd and its the latest version of Apache

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to superuser.com instead of closing?

Comment: Here's a quick way: `find / -name httpd.conf`

Comment: For red hat, usually: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-config.html

Comment: mine was in /etc/httpd/conf.d

Comment: Here's another quick way: ```locate httpd.conf```

Comment: On ubuntu you may have apache2.conf file and not an httpd.conf file. You can find the file listed under /etc/apache2 directory

Answer (score 654, accepted):

Get the path of running Apache

```
$ ps -ef | grep apache
apache   12846 14590  0 Oct20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Append `-V` argument to the path

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

Reference:
http://commanigy.com/blog/2011/6/8/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location

Comment: In some OS's you will get the relative path of conf file : -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf" You can run "/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep HTTPD_ROOT" to find the root. Output: "-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" The absolute path will be then : "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

Comment: Doesn't work on my shared host since ps only shows tasks running as me. I had to just try running "httpd -V" and "apache2ctl -V" as Rich Bower suggests.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2 and `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` gives me some warning errors `Invalid Mutex directory` so the right command I used is `sudo apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. It just returns the PID of grep.

Answer (score 215):

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout for discussion of where you might find Apache httpd configuration files on various platforms, since this can vary from release to release and platform to platform. The most common answer, however, is either /etc/apache/conf or /etc/httpd/conf

Generically, you can determine the answer by running the command:

> httpd -V

(That's a capital V). Or, on systems where httpd is renamed, perhaps `apache2ctl -V`

This will return various details about how httpd is built and configured, including the default location of the main configuration file.

One of the lines of output should look like:

> -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"

which, combined with the line:

> -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"

will give you a full path to the default location of the configuration file

Comment: For me, what worked is the `apache2ctl -V` command and looking for the path in what is listed after.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: yep, `apache2ctl` is not *renamed* version of `httpd`, it's different names of same aplication on [Debian- and RedHat-based OS](http://askubuntu.com/a/533125/325716) respectively

Comment: apache2ctl -V worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Nothing else did.

Comment: I get `the command httpd` was not found.

Comment: Yes, EdwardBlack, and if you'll read the entire posting, you'll note that it has different names on different distros.

Comment: Try "apachectl -V" if "httpd -V" don't work

Comment: On ubuntu you may have apache2.conf file and not an httpd.conf file. You can find the file listed under /etc/apache2 directory