# how to create a httpd.conf file

Tags: linux, apache, hosting

I would like to create a httpd.conf file to upload to my Apache server. I need to create this file in order to configure the  SSLCertificateChainFile. Does anybody have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you want to create it. You just need to find and configure it. You may try **[this](http://commanigy.com/blog/2011/6/8/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location)**:

It's possible to configure this there is no "default location" so I usually do:

```
$ ps -ef | grep apache
```

which gives me a list like

```
deploy@cmd01:/$ ps -ef | grep apache
root      4053     1  0 06:26 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www       5189  4053  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www       5199  4053  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
...
```

Then simply run

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V
```

and you will get the details you need, specifically this

Server compiled with....

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The httpd.conf file is typically present, you should just be able to add your specific config settings in there.

[Where is my httpd.conf file located apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache)