# codeigniter remove index.php gives 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I put code in .htaccess under is htaccess code and also change in config.php file but still it gives 404 error please any one help me to find what was the issue in that hear is the link of site `http://198.12.149.211/~physrec/`

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://198.12.149.211/~physrec/";

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci_intro/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_intro/index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you want to remove index.php from your URLs , then make sure to do the following in application/config/config.php - $config['index_page'] = ''

Comment: i just put $config['index_page'] = '' but it is not working still

Comment: Just now, i clicked on the above link, the page is opening and I am not getting 404 error.

Comment: home is open but other menu page is not working that gives 404

Comment: Modify your rewrite rule and remove /ci_intro/ from there.. e.g. your last rewrite rule should be - RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: RewriteBase '/ci_intro/' is become only '/' ? you meanes where ci_intro found it will removed

Comment: No, there is no need of '/' here, just try this: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]"

Comment: nup dud not working ? RewriteBase /ci_intro/ is removed from in htaccess

Comment: I think you are doing the wrong change, dont modify RewriteBase, that is required, you just have to modify your RewriteRule. Let me rewrite the .htaccess file in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /ci_intro/

   #Removes access to the system folder by users.
   #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
   #previously this would not have been possible.
   #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

   #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
   #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
   #Submitted by: Fabdrol
   #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

   #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
   #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
   #request to index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have the following in your httpd.conf file, if not then modify your conf file and restart apache.

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
 </Directory>
```

Also, make sure rewrite is on in your apache configuration

Comment: I am assuming your base directory is 'ci_intro' and you have enabled mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf file.

Comment: where i found httpd.conf file

Comment: depends on what version of apache you are using. mostly it should be in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: my etc folder is empty no files or directories in that

Comment: Check this to figure out where is your httpd.conf : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Comment: have you checked this: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf , you are not on shared hosting, right.

Comment: i have WHM on goddady i have five site on that all have problem like this

Comment: Have you tested your website on local environments? Also, check the validity of your controllers.

Comment: ya it is working my other server but on this is not working ? {-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess file to,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Change your config file from,

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

to,

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Also this example will be helpfull,
http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/