# Web hosting server outputs php files to the web browser instead of parsing them

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been hosting my site coded in PHP on one shared server. The site worked just fine. So recently I migrated it to a new web hosting service, after which the server started literally outputting contents of the php scripts/files to the web browser!

The `.htaccess` file was configured as such (to parse `htm` files as `php`):

```
<Files index.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
</Files>
```

Any idea why it's not parsing them?

PS. I'm also curious how to prevent outputting of PHP scripts to the client browser in plain text in the future?

Comment: Check the server configuration on your new hosting service; either they don't support PHP, or they don't allow you to change the configuration in htaccess.

Comment: `Allow Override` is not setup in such a way to give your user the ability to modify the `AddType` method, or the usage of an `.htaccess` is strictly prohibited. Also, while it shouldnt' be necessary, you can perform `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Yes, it supports running PHP files (if they have `.php` extension.)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your new web hosting service allows you to use `.htaccess` files.  Some hosting companies disable that functionality for safety concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `http.conf` include the PHP MIME type. ie, make sure you have this line and thatit's not commented out:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Also make sure AllowOverride is enabled

`AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thanks. Where would I find that `http.conf` file?

Comment: depends on your server, but here's how to find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I can access it on this shared web hosting account.

Comment: If not, your host provide will be happy to fix it for you, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your new hosting provider does not allow short open tags and you use them ?

If you put `<? echo "Hello world"; ?>` in `hello.php` the file is parsed or not ? If its not, try to replace `<?` with `<?php` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you want to parse only the `index.htm` you should not put the
   AddType directive inside the `<Files index.htm>...</Files>` directive.
2. What you actually need is [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) not [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).
   Place just this line in you .htaccess:

   ```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
   ```

   Note: `application/x-httpd-php` is both a content-type as well as a handler name for PHP

Comment: Although yes, I do need it for the `index.htm` file only, I tried it the way you put it and it didn't work. It still output PHP script as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this fixed. My `.htaccess` file should've been this:

```
<Files index.htm>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php52 .htm
</Files>
```

I didn't realize it had to be so specific.