# How to resolve this error I got after PHP version upgrade “The apache2 configtest failed.”?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2, php-5.5

I'm using ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS on my machine. I was using PHP 5.3.10 Now I upgraded to PHP 5.5.18 by using few commands on terminal. After I upgraded to latest PHP version I checked the version by using command php -v. It shown me the PHP version is 5.5.18.
But when I tried to access one directory from the folder "www" i.e. document root I'm getting error "Unable to connect" in browser. When I enter only localhost in address bar "It Works" is the message appearing.

So I tried to restart the apache server ny using following command :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then I got following error :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

After reading this message I go to the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and checked line no. 214 there I got found following statement written :

```
Include httpd.conf
```

So can someone please help me in working the thing as it is like previous for me? Please suggest me the ways I can fix this issue.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: Does the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` exist? Check to see whether you renamed or moved it previously and update the reference in the `apache2.conf` file.

Comment: @Joe:No, it's not existing.

Comment: Ok, then just try to find out where your httpd.conf file is located and update the `Include`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Comment: @Joe: Itried using this command : sudo find / -name httpd.conf
but it shown nothing to me.

Comment: Have you tried the commands from the first answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63307/discussion-between-phplover-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
a2dismod php5
```

OR

```
a2dismod php7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

### it also woked for me

`sudo a2dismod php7.0`

```
Module php7.0 disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart


mr@mr ~/Desktop $ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if two symbolic link there for php same version [cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/]

   - php7.load -> ../mods-available/php7.load
   - php7.load -> ../mods-available/php7.0.load
   - I have removed one of them according to my requirement
2. Check available modes in [/etc/apache2/mods-available/]

   - Php7.0.load
   - Php7.load
   - I have removed one of them [php7.load] Enable on of the mode restart
     apache server