# Moodle - How to enable slash arguments on apache2 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: moodle

Title says it all :) 
at docs.moodle.org it says to include "AcceptPathInfo On" in httpd.conf but I can't find where this file is and at what line to include this.

Please help, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer here : [Where is my httpd.conf file located apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache)

Use this to find the folder and the conf file name for apache.

```
apache2ctl -V
```

Thank you for the heads up about the slash arguments too, I didn't realise they would be required in future versions of Moodle

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Using_slash_arguments