# htaccess language conversion

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a website for arabic and english. All the files are stored in the root directory. I didn't made any separate folder for arabic or english nor any file for arabic or english. I just made a two language array for arabic or english. If url says arabic then data from arrayarabic will fetch and same case of english.

What I am requesting to convert
My current url is

```
http://www.example.com/viewjob.php?job_id=11031
```

I want to convert if to 
`http://www.example.com/ar/viewjob.php?job_id=11031` but there is no separate folder for ar.

Please let me know... thanks.

Comment: what get-parameter you use to choose language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this quite easily with mod_rewrite. When an url starts with either "ar" or "en", you want to take the rest of the url, and internally rewrite to the rest of the url and append a parameter to the rest of the query string:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(en|ar)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Brother, do i to change all the url to include ar or en ?? like http://www.example.com/viewjob.php?job_id=11031 to http://www.example.com/ar/viewjob.php?job_id=11031. Now my url doesn't inlucde ar or en.

Comment: This work excatly the required. Thank you very very much... love your answer.

Comment: The urls on your site need to be changed so they include the language. If they are relative it will automatically go well, but you'll need to make css/js/image urls absolute.

Comment: Dear, its working in local server but not on the live server. Please could you help me again. the domain is http://afaqemployment.com/employers.php is working fine but http://afaqemployment.com/ar/employers.php

Comment: Enable mod_rewrite ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)) and make sure that `AllowOverride` is at least `FileInfo` in the main config file.

Comment: Brother, please hold on, i'll check and let you know. I have the below code in my file # Lines That should already be in your .htacess
<Files "config.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>


Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^(en|ar)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: The main config file is httpd.conf, not a .htaccess file.

Comment: But i cannot find this file in my server may be its hidden. How can i access this ? can i make a new file and add to my root ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Comment: Ok bro, thanks.. i fed up.. i cannot find. I'll use session to change the language. thanks.