# i get a 404 while loading the homepage with Index.php, but index.php works on direct links, why?

Tags: php, html, apache

I can't seem to understand why my *`Homepage`* has suddenly refused to load directly i.e: `www.mysite.com/` but loads only if you type `www.mysite.com/index.php`

This is the Site:

**COMPARE**:

> `http://www.propasiarealty.com // Sends you to the 404 page`

**WHEREAS**:

> `http://www.propasiarealty.com/index.php  // Loads the homepage.`

Can't figure out exactly what is wrong, please help.

Bellow is a *Filezilla* screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT 01**

Please see my HTACCESS... Snapshot
[image]

---

**UPDATE 02**
 I have modified the HTACCESS still no success, now looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#ErrorDocument 400     /400.html

#ErrorDocument 401     /401.html 

ErrorDocument 403     /errs/404.php

ErrorDocument 404     /errs/404.php

#ErrorDocument 500     /500.html

Options -Indexes
```

But still not Working

---

**UPDATE 03 [This worked]**

The Solution as suggested by ***@HPierce*** was to modify the HTACCESS to look something like bellow:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php


RewriteEngine on  

RewriteRule ^$ index.php

    #ErrorDocument 400     /400.html

    #ErrorDocument 401     /401.html 

    ErrorDocument 403     /errs/404.php

    ErrorDocument 404     /errs/404.php

    #ErrorDocument 500     /500.html

    Options -Indexes
```

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Comment: Please see Edit with HTACCESS Snapshot. Ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new declaration for `DirectoryIndex` in your .htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

With Apache, the default `DirectoryIndex` will be set to **index.html** which is different than your **index.php** page that you want to serve.

Alternatively you might want to specify both files as your `DirectoryIndex`

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

This would check for *index.html* first then *index.php* if *index.html* is not available. This might be the better solution, as changing the defaults may confuse anyone else that has to work on your website.

Apache docs on mod_dir: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

If that doesn't work, you might consider adding a rewrite rule - though it's not recommended. Rewrite rules interrupt the incoming HTTP request and reforms it to match the way your server is set up.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
```

This rewrite rule matches only requests to `http://www.propasiarealty.com` and **will not match** `http://www.propasiarealty.com/`

Using rewrite rules requires mod_rewrite to be installed - more info here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Do you have access to httpd.conf, Apache's global config file? If so, post some of the contents of that - special emphasis on any lines that have `AllowOverrides` on it.

Comment: Wherez the `httpd.conf` located at?

Comment: `$ apachectl -V` should tell you (it varies from environment to environment). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Comment: Ooops, I dont think I can get to that File... This is the First time am Facing this issue, and kinda tried almost everything I know so far... What else could possibly cause such a misbehavior?..Again thanks for suggestions!!

Comment: I'm hesitant to suggest this, because it is such a horrible dirty hack that shouldn't be needed here. But try adding this to your `.htaccess` file:

`RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^$ index.php` Where `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteRule` are on different lines. You can test it here and prove that it would work with an appropriately configured server: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Wow!!!.... That super worked. You can add that: `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^$ index.php` in your answer and am gonna accept it as the Solution to my type of problem... Ty!!