# keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to hit an endpoint from my API to authenticate a user from Keycloak, but it's giving me error `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` on the Keycloak page. I have created my own realm apart from master. Keycloak is running on HTTP.

Comment: while checking through inspect element its showing 500 error

Comment: Please do not post the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45356800/741249) multiple times. If you want to add more details to your original question, you can do that by clicking on  'edit' directly below your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keycloak invalid parameter redirect\_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356800/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri)

Comment: Check for https vs http in the redirect url

Comment: In my case it was a dumb mistake: "<IP address>" instead of "http://<IP address>"

Comment: I don't know if this is overly simplistic understanding of the question, but for us we were using keycloak-js and the config takes a param of redirectUri and we were used redirect_url as a key param.

Answer (score 127):

What worked for me was adding wildchar **'*'**. Although for production builds, I am going to be more specific with the value of this field. But for dev purposes you can do this.

[image]

Setting available under, *keycloak admin console -> Realm_Name -> Cients -> Client_Name*.

EDIT: ***DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION. Doing so creates a large security flaw.***

Comment: This answer may be a dangerous security flaw, doing so you open the door to the insecure redirect attack.

Comment: I can't believe this answer currently has top votes. This is far from a solution and it should really only appear in comments. On the other hand, there is too few information in the question to even try to answer.

Comment: @tryingToLearn can you help me with this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024164/access-token-generated-by-one-keycloak-instance-is-invalid-on-other

Comment: I was having `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` error, the problem was my client ID was wrong ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 63):

If you are a .Net Devloper Please Check below  Configurations
 keycloakAuthentication options class set
CallbackPath = RedirectUri,//this Property needs to be set other wise it will show invalid redirecturi error

I faced the same error. In my case, the issue was with  **Valid Redirect URIs** was not correct. So these are the steps I followed.

First login to keycloack as an admin user. 
Then Select your realm(maybe you will auto-direct to the realm). Then you will see below screen

[image]

Select **Clients** from left panel. 
Then select relevant client which you configured for your app.
By default, you will be **Setting** tab, if not select it.
My app was running on port 3000, so my correct setting is like below.
let say you have an app runs on localhost:3000, so your setting should be like this

[image]

Comment: web origins you could have put `http://localhost:3000` as well instead of *

Answer (score 30):

### If you're getting this error because of a new realm you created

You can directly change the URL in the URL bar to get past this error. In the URL that you are redirected to (you may have to look in Chrome dev tools for this URL), change the realm from `master` to the one you just created, and if you are not using `https`, then make sure the redirect_uri is also using `http`.

### If you're getting this error because you're trying to setup Keycloak on a public facing domain (not localhost)

**Step 1)**
Follow [this documentation](https://wiki.communecter.org/en/keycloak-_-configuration.html#configure-the-mysql-database) to setup a MySql database (link's broken. If you find some good alternative documentation that works for you, feel free to update this link and remove this message). You may also need to refer to [this documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#modify-the-keycloak-datasource).

**Step 2)**
Run the command `update REALM set ssl_required = 'NONE' where id = 'master';`

**Note:**
At this point, you should technically be able to login, but version 4.0 of Keycloak is using https for the redirect uri even though we just turned off https support. Until Keycloak fixes this, we can get around this with a reverse proxy. A reverse proxy is something we will want to use anyhow to easily create SSL/TLS certificates without having to worry about Java keystores.

**Note 2:** After writing these instructions, Keycloak come out with their own proxy. They then stopped supporting it and recommended using [oauth2 proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider/#keycloak-auth-provider) instead. It is lacking some features the Keycloak proxy had, and an unoffical version of that proxy is still being maintained [here](https://github.com/oneconcern/keycloak-gatekeeper). I haven't tried using either of these proxies, but at this point, you might want to stop following my directions and use one of those instead.

**Step 3)** Install Apache. We will use Apache as a reverse proxy (I tried NGINX, but NGINX had some limitations that got in the way). See [yum installing Apache](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-on-centos-7/) (CentOs 7), and [apt-get install Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) (Ubuntu 16), or find instructions for your specific distro.

**Step 4)** Run Apache

- Use `sudo systemctl start httpd` (CentOs) or `sudo systemctl start apache2` (Ubuntu)
- Use `sudo systemctl status httpd` (CentOs) or `sudo systemctl status apache2`
  (Ubuntu) to check if Apache is running. If you see in green text the words `active (running)` or if the last entry reads `Started The Apache HTTP Server.` then you're good.

**Step 5)** We will establish a SSL connection with the reverse proxy, and then the reverse proxy will communicate to keyCloak over http. Because this http communication is happening on the same machine, you're still secure. We can use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions) to setup auto-renewing certificates.

If this type of encryption is not good enough, and your security policy requires end-to-end encryption, you will have to figure out how to [setup SSL through WildFly](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#enabling-ssl-https-for-the-keycloak-server), instead of using a reverse proxy.

**Note:**
I was never actually able to get https to work properly with the admin portal. Perhaps this may have just been a bug in the beta version of Keycloak 4.0 that I'm using. You're suppose to be able to set the SSL level to only require it for external requests, but this did not seem to work, which is why we set https to none in step #2. From here on we will continue to use http over an SSH tunnel to manage the admin settings.

**Step 6)**
Whenever you try to visit the site via https, you will trigger an HSTS policy which will auto-force http requests to redirect to https. Follow these instructions to [clear the HSTS rule from Chrome](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/clear-hsts-browser/), and then for the time being, do not visit the https version of the site again.

**Step 7)**
Configure Apache. Add the virtual host config in the code block below. If you've never done this, then the first thing you'll need to do is figure out where to add this config file.

*On RHEL and some other distros*
you'll need to find where your [httpd.conf or apache2.conf file is located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/lost-httpd-conf-file-located-apache). That config file should be loading virtual host config files from another folder such as `conf.d`.

*If you are using Ubuntu or Debian,*
your config files will be located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and you'll have an extra step of needing to  enable them by running the command `sudo a2ensite name-of-your-conf-file.conf`. That'll create a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` which is where Apache looks for config files on Ubuntu/Debian (and remember the config file was placed in sites-available, slightly different).

*All distros*
Once you've found the config files, change out, or add, the following virtual host entries in your config files. Make sure you don't override the already present SSL options that where generated by certbot. When done, your config file should look something like this.

```apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    #change https redirect_uri parameters to http
    RewriteCond %{request_uri}\?%{query_string} ^(.*)redirect_uri=https(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1redirect_uri=http%2 [NE,R=302]

    #uncomment to force https
    #does not currently work
    #RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

    #forward the requests on to keycloak
    ProxyPreserveHost On    
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RewriteEngine on

    #Disable HSTS
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0; includeSubDomains;" env=HTTPS


    #change https redirect_uri parameters to http
    RewriteCond %{request_uri}\?%{query_string} ^(.*)redirect_uri=https(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1redirect_uri=http%2 [NE,R=302]

    #forward the requests on to keycloak
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    #Leave the items added by certbot alone
    #There should be a ServerName option
    #And a bunch of options to configure the location of the SSL cert files
    #Along with an option to include an additional config file

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Step 8)** Restart Apache. Use `sudo systemctl restart httpd` (CentOs) or `sudo systemctl restart apache2` (Ubuntu).

**Step 9)**
Before you have a chance to try to login to the server, since we told Keycloak to use http, we need to setup another method of connecting securely. This can be done by either installing a VPN service on the keycloak server, or by using SOCKS. I used a SOCKS proxy. In order to do this, you'll first need to setup dynamic port forwarding.

`ssh -N -D 9905 user@example.com`

Or set it up via [Putty](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel#step-1-windows-%E2%80%94-setting-up-the-tunnel).

All traffic sent to port 9905 will now be securely routed through an SSH tunnel to your server. Make sure you whitelist port 9905 on your server's firewall.

Once you have dynamic port forwarding setup, you will need to setup your browser to use a SOCKS proxy on port 9905. [Instructions here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel).

**Step 10)** You should now be able to login to the Keycloak admin portal. To connect to the website go to http://127.0.0.1, and the SOCKS proxy will take you to the admin console. Make sure you turn off the SOCKS proxy when you're done as it does utilize your server's resources, and will result in a slower internet speed for you if kept on.

**Step 11)** Don't ask me how long it took me to figure all of this out.

Comment: This was the line that cought my attention :

#change https redirect_uri parameters to http
RewriteCond %{request_uri}\?%{query_string} ^(.*)redirect_uri=https(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1redirect_uri=http%2 [NE,R=302]

I'm using nginx but, as soon as I substituted the https to http on the redirect_uri it worked.

Comment: Does anyone have the updated links for this answer?

Comment: I've fixed the links that I could fix, and have brought everything up to date.

Answer (score 23):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE IN KEYCLOAK 18**

In the newest keycloak 18, they have deprecated the redirect_uri variable for the openid connect logout -> https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#openid-connect-logout

Comment: just want to add that if that error occurs on the master login for Keycloak 18, it might be a bug: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11667

Comment: @Havrin it seems I'm affecting by this bug, getting the `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` error in the login page. Did you find a workaround for it?

Comment: never mind, I was missing the proper redirect URL in the settings. resolved

Answer (score 12):

Log in the Keycloak admin console website, select the realm and its client, then make sure all URIs of the client are prefixed with the protocol, that is, with `http://` for example. An example would be `http://localhost:8082/*`

Another way to solve the issue, is to view the Keycloak server console output, locate the line stating the request was refused, copy from it the `redirect_uri` displayed value and paste it in the `* Valid Redirect URIs` field of the client in the Keycloak admin console website. The requested URI is then one of the acceptables.

Comment: In my case I was missing * at the end of the url  while configuring Valid redirect URIs in the client settings of admin console

Answer (score 11):

Go to keycloak admin console > SpringBootKeycloak> Cients>login-app page.
Here in valid-redirect uris section add
http://localhost:8080/sso/login

This will help resolve indirect-uri problem

Comment: The problem is that the admin console is not accessible.

Comment: I got this problem after I modified Keycloak's `web-context` setting

Answer (score 10):

**[For Keycloak version 18 or Higher]**

None of the mentioned solutions should be working if you are using **Keycloak 18** or a higher version.

According to the [version 18 release note](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/04/keycloak-1800-released). Keycloak does not support logout with **redirect_uri** anymore. you need to include **post_logout_redirect_uri**  and **id_token_hint** as parameters.

Please check the answer of this question for more information.
[keycloak: using react user can login but when I try logout I get a message "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984843/keycloak-using-react-user-can-login-but-when-i-try-logout-i-get-a-message-inva)

Comment: How & where are these `post_logout_redirect_uri` and `id_token_hint` parameters to be used?

Comment: you can get the logout URL from the .well-known openid configurations link of the Keycloak realm. Then you need to provide id_token_hint and post_logout_redirect_uri as url parameters. id_token_hint => id token issued for that user at the authentication. post_logout_redirect_url => the url you need user to be redirected after successful logout. (this url should be mentioned in the client settings as a valid redirect URI)

Answer (score 9):

For me, I had a missing trailing slash `/` in the value for `Valid Redirect URIs`

Answer (score 7):

If you're seeing this problem after you've made a modification to the Keycloak context path, you'll need to make an additional change to a redirect url setting:

1. Change `<web-context>yourchange/auth</web-context>` back to
   `<web-context>auth</web-context>` in standalone.xml
2. Restart Keycloak and navigate to the login page (`/auth/admin`)
3. Log in and select the "Master" realm
4. Select "Clients" from the side menu
5. Select the "security-admin-console" client from the list that appears
6. Change the "Valid Redirect URIs" from `/auth/admin/master/console/*` to
   `/yourchange/auth/admin/master/console/*`
7. Save and sign out.  You'll again see the "Invalid redirect url" message after signing out.
8. Now, put in your original change
   `<web-context>yourchange/auth</web-context>` in standalone.xml
   Restart Keycloak and navigate to the login page (which is now
   `/yourchange/auth/admin`)
9. Log in and enjoy

Comment: alternatively, you can edit table `redirect_uris` in the DB and adjust the value fields

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. I rectified it by going to the particular client under the realm respectively therein redirect URL add * after your complete URL.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with "localhost" in the redirect URL. Change to 127.0.0.1 in the "Valid Redirect URIs" field of clients config (KeyCloak web admin console). It works for me.

Comment: oh, thank you for the tip. helped me to trace my issue

Comment: same case for me as well, somehow worked with `127.0.0.1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this problem can occur if you put whitespace in your Realm name. I had name set to `Debugging Realm` and I got this error. When I changed to `DebuggingRealm` it worked.

You can still have whitespace in the display name. Odd that keycloak doesn't check for this on admin input.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this problem too.  After two days of pulling my hair out I discovered that the URLs in Keycloak are case sensitive.  However the browser coverts the URL to lowercase, which means that uppercase URLs in Keycloak will never work.

e.g. my server name is MYSERVER (hostname returns MYSERVER)

```
Keycloak URLs are https://MYSERVER:8080/*
Browse to https://myserver:8080 -> fails invalid_url
Browse to https://MYSERVER:8080 -> fails invalid_url
Change Keycloak URLs to https://myserver:8080/*
Browse to https://myserver:8080 -> works
Browse to https://MYSERVER:8080 -> works
```

Answer (score 5):

In your client, set the origin of your request. In my case, localhost:3000 (javaScript client)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

even I faced the same issue. I rectified it by going to the particular client under the realm respectively therein redirect URL add * after your complete URL.

THE PROBLEM WILL BE SOLVED

**Example:**
     redirect URI: http:localhost:3000/myapp/generator/*

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the exact rewrite was key for me.  the wellKnownUrl lookup was returning "http://127.0.01:7070/" and I had specified "http://localhost:7070" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

We also saw this, but only on certain URLs. [After seeing this clue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9450), I realized that the Java URI constructor has to be able to decode it,
like so `URI uri = URI.create(redirectUri);`

We had a `{` and `}` in our URLs which normally worked fine, but when going through two layers of URL decode/encode, Java decided the `{` and `}` were invalid.

We'll be changing our curly braces to something else to get around the double encode/decode issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the lib in react:

```
"keycloak-js": "^21.1.1",
```

This can solve by adding the value of `Valid post logout redirect URIs` as an example: see the screenshot below:
[image: Valid post logout redirect URIs]

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the keycloak admin console for fronted configuration. It must be wrongly configured for redirect url and web origins.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the Invalid parameter: redirect_uri problem problem while following spring boot and keycloak example available at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak. when adding the client from the keycloak server we have to provide the redirect URI for that client so that keycloak server can perform the redirection.
When I faced the same error multiple times, I followed copying correct URL from keycloak server console and provided in the valid Redirect URIs space and it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

This error is also thrown when your User does not have the expected Role delegated in User definition(Set role for the Realm in drop down).

Answer (score 3):

Your redirect URI in your code(keycloak.init) should be the same as the redirect URI set on Keycloak server (client -> Valid Uri)
[image: click to view image of my code]
[image: click to view my keycloak settings]

Answer (score 3):

I know other people provided the same answer, but my reputation was not high enough to upvote them. In the redirect menu, Mine had a redirect of " 0.0.0.0:8080/* ". I added

(actualIP) followed by :8080/* and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Authorization Code Flow then the `response_type` query param must be equal to `code`. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_admin/topics/sso-protocols/oidc.html

Answer (score 2):

if somebody uses keycloak-js it can be old (like ^17.0.0) if you update it onto ^20.0.3 it supports "post_logout_redirect_uri" and work with new keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to redirect to the keycloak login page after logout (as I was), that is not allowed by default but also needs to be configured in the "Valid Redirect URIs" setting in the admin console of your client.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the value of the redirect_uri parameter is whitelisted for the client that you are using. You can manage the configuration of the client via the admin console.

The redirect uri should match exactly with one of the whitelisted redirect uri's, or you can use a wildcard at the end of the uri you want to whitelist. See: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_clients

Note that using wildcards to whitelist redirect uri's is allowed by Keycloak, but is actually a violation of the OpenId Connect specification. See the discussion on this at https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2018-December/011440.html

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by the wrong client_id (OPENID_CLIENT_ID) I had defined in the deployment.yaml. Make sure this field is assigned with the one in Keycloak client id.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems related to an invalid value in **Valid Redirect URIs** field. You can try with one of these tips:

1. set the same value of **Client ID** (if it's a URL) making it end with `/*` , or
2. tryingToLearn 's reponse [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420355/97799]  (but beware of security issues).

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue because I create a realm with two words and had a space on it. eg Test Realm, this gave me this error. I put an underscore and was good to go eg, Test_Realm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 20.0.2 and, for me, the solution was to simply add a '+' in the "Valid post logout redirect URIs" field:

[image: Valid post logout redirect URIs setting]

As stated in the help balloon, "A value of '+' will use the list of valid redirect uris".

Answer (score -1):

In **Access settings**, Adding these 2 **Valid redirect URIs** worked for me when I was going through the [docker tutorial](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker) of keycloak 19.0.1:

```
https://www.keycloak.org/*
http://localhost:8080
```

Notice the `http` and `https` protocols.

Comment: Where should these be set?

Answer (score -2):

In my solution:
you must add the url in textbox:

- Valid Redirect URIs
  with the same url you must add in your app.
  Hope this help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).