# Keycloak authentication with Electron App

Tags: react-router, electron, keycloak

Hi I've been stuck on this for days! I'm trying to use keycloak to authenticate my electron app after converting my react app using this [guide](https://medium.com/@mjangir70/turn-the-famous-react-boilerplate-into-electron-desktop-application-68d91dce8d3a).

When I run 'npm run electron:dev' , keycloak redirects to the login page. However, when I run 'npm run electron:prod' this fails.

Logs from keycloak server shows:

```
Server:server-one] 08:58:31,575 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-3) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=codingpedia, clientId=my-ui, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=file:///home/mycompany/john/projects/boilerplate-javascript-electron/app/build/index.html
```

Notice that the redirect_uri is 'file:///...' which I believe to be the cause of it.

I've also tried to change the below but it does not resolve the problem.

```
// import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';
```

Why is this working in dev but not in prod? Is there something I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did the answer below helped you somehow? Thanks!

Comment: The below answer does not address the problem. It works in dev because it's using the web pack dev server whereas in production it is completely file based.

Comment: @johnwick0831, Did you found resolve your problem ?

Comment: No, @michal we never got to the bottom of that unfortunately.

Comment: Any luck after 1 year?

Answer (score 0):

It works in dev probably because the "index.html" file is located in your computer (file:///home/mycompany/john/projects/boilerplate-javascript-electron/app/build/index.html).

[This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352880/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri) tells how to properly set the redirect_uri parameter, through the admin console.

Note: make sure you can remotely access your index.html in prod, using a browser or any other client tool (HTTP GET).