# keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri behind a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, keycloak

How do you correctly configure NGINX as a proxy in front of Keycloak?

Asking & answering this as doc because I've had to do it repeatedly now and forget the details after a while.

This is specifically dealing with the case where Keycloak is behind a reverse proxy e.g. nginx and NGINX is terminating SSL and pushing to Keycloak. This is not the same issue as [keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352880/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri) although it produces the same error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to this is in the docs at 
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#identifying-client-ip-addresses

The `proxy-address-forwarding` must be set as well as the various `X-...` headers.

If you're using the Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ then set the env. arg `-e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`.

```
server {
  server_name api.domain.com;

  location /auth {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;

 }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
  }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name api.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If you're using another proxy the important parts of this is the headers that are being set:

```
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Apache, ISTIO and others have their own means of setting these.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above deals with configuration done to the proxy.

In what respects the keycloak container, if you are getting the redirect_uri error when trying to log into the admin console,  there are two environment variables that have to be set for Keycloak (as of version 10.0.2) to work behind a reverse proxy.

If the URL of the admin console is https://your.fqdn/auth then you must set:

```
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL = https://your.fqdn/auth
```

along with the above-mentioned:

```
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING = true
```

Below is a minimal **docker-compose.yml** that will launch keycloak 10 behind a reverse proxy that forwards requests to https://your.fqdn onto the docker hosts's port 8000. Just set the variables `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PWD` and `PG_KC_PASS` in the environment (or .env file) when launching, according to your wishes.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  pgkeycloak-data:
services:

  pg-keycloak:
    image: "postgres:12-alpine"
    container_name: pg-keycloak
    volumes:
      - "pgkeycloak-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloakdb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_KC_PASS}

  auth:
    user: root
    privileged: true
    image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.2"
    depends_on:
      - "pg-keycloak"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:443
    command:
      -Djboss.http.port=443
      -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PWD}
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: https://your.fqdn/auth
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      DB_USER: keycloakdb
      DB_PASSWORD: ${PG_KC_PASS}
      DB_ADDR: pg-keycloak
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that very same problem because I reused/copy-pasted a proxy config from another service.

Once I changed `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` to `proxy_set_header Host $host;` it worked.

(removed **:$server_port**)