# Keycloak complains about invalid redirect_uri on token endpoint

Tags: java, servlet-filters, keycloak

I try to migrate a existing Java application running on CloudFoundry to Keycloak and therefore use the Keycloak Servlet Filter. This is working in the first step to request the code. But the second step to turn the code into a token fails with "Incorrect redirect_uri". This is weird because I can see in both requests to the Keycloak server then same URL as redirect_url.

Does anybody know the reason and a solution for this?

```
2019-01-11T12:03:20.01+0100 [RTR/1] OUT APP_HOST - [2019-01-11T11:03:19.993+0000] "GET /keycloak/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 0 "https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?state=f98ebe4e-1499-4513-8da3-1a95bd0ce894&session_state=9984091c-6eb7-4395-a335-27aff1334a5f&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..zEDr2g5BhXmaNr6vflO7eg.Lm6SpGasJYE-CJqkwiAmWz4sRHGUMgYHFjNr-ScWamsSL6vRSj_r-Gbsf75-FNxt4NMC6XTshNXoeqTA0SJOrQSnPMV1qLuJyAHWY-ajAiDkPvtsWT5nxHYbEUaJtDOAMbxhtfl3yQo_Uyl2gYegcJTgC7FchC8FSl5ovS7q3EZb8aXET0OP_-IApQo0xN4XB2BDuiuC_DY1ySlYkUYdKSrK4HsgSlkSHELBwyL0iw8CNs0nlnWHgJZBWtYDVoRk.QuT_ov_ZBlFhexBrZAYl_w" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "192.168.6.12:50100" "192.168.2.30:61006" x_forwarded_for:"10.209.173.45, 192.168.6.12" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"b18a1abd-233b-4140-5e8a-8ae1a16ca251" response_time:0.017485509 app_id:"27846aa1-34c0-46e0-9dce-c7a893d06dd6" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"9399df2a769b38c6" x_b3_spanid:"9399df2a769b38c6" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2019-01-11T12:03:20.01+0100 [RTR/1] OUT 
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,004 [DEBUG] PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] adminRequest https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,006 [DEBUG] PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:106) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] checkCorsPreflight https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,006 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:266) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] there was no code
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,007 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:274) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] redirecting to auth server
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,007 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.getRedirectUri(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:144) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] callback uri: https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?
2019-01-11T12:03:20.00+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:20,008 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.challenge(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:227) [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Sending redirect to login page: https://KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/realms/kums/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FAPP_HOST%2Fkeycloak%2F?&state=5dc5b208-6093-4d1b-b9ed-c9d2091a306f&login=true&scope=openid
2019-01-11T12:03:21.79+0100 [RTR/0] OUT APP_HOST - [2019-01-11T11:03:21.692+0000] "GET /keycloak/?state=5dc5b208-6093-4d1b-b9ed-c9d2091a306f&session_state=9984091c-6eb7-4395-a335-27aff1334a5f&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..0-5C1AJAZrNXJwmZbt4I0Q.LET3bu8MVK6Uq58-j-yPC0WP_F01jskmm6WvyXqRRURlMiVIH9VV0fx6Cc3O4X0JFyTUiuESHUcfk2dyHOoL_z-IVVAAxTE-Eg2rphKjVT7OfWsoxuHZKFY9RkyEnr9Grwgd9WakmrGZBAin8yVX6YmfLC6O1KkrVwiJDrB3lP6VrlWRCMrlmBnjMlqwzFD_Bx3vqSmoKlWo9I9b5bvPgcFZY58EO2zARsBmLAjqtSZTdDB9dasohuPjXpDa9lOR.sO5oOhIQKC6NcHC3CIIuzA HTTP/1.1" 403 0 5878 "https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?state=f98ebe4e-1499-4513-8da3-1a95bd0ce894&session_state=9984091c-6eb7-4395-a335-27aff1334a5f&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..zEDr2g5BhXmaNr6vflO7eg.Lm6SpGasJYE-CJqkwiAmWz4sRHGUMgYHFjNr-ScWamsSL6vRSj_r-Gbsf75-FNxt4NMC6XTshNXoeqTA0SJOrQSnPMV1qLuJyAHWY-ajAiDkPvtsWT5nxHYbEUaJtDOAMbxhtfl3yQo_Uyl2gYegcJTgC7FchC8FSl5ovS7q3EZb8aXET0OP_-IApQo0xN4XB2BDuiuC_DY1ySlYkUYdKSrK4HsgSlkSHELBwyL0iw8CNs0nlnWHgJZBWtYDVoRk.QuT_ov_ZBlFhexBrZAYl_w" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "192.168.6.12:47988" "192.168.2.30:61006" x_forwarded_for:"10.209.173.45, 192.168.6.12" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"25f4b5df-a11e-4120-7ec8-2910671b4819" response_time:0.101218652 app_id:"27846aa1-34c0-46e0-9dce-c7a893d06dd6" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"b743963318cc0d09" x_b3_spanid:"b743963318cc0d09" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.79+0100 [RTR/0] OUT 
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,702 [DEBUG] PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] adminRequest https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..0-5C1AJAZrNXJwmZbt4I0Q.LET3bu8MVK6Uq58-j-yPC0WP_F01jskmm6WvyXqRRURlMiVIH9VV0fx6Cc3O4X0JFyTUiuESHUcfk2dyHOoL_z-IVVAAxTE-Eg2rphKjVT7OfWsoxuHZKFY9RkyEnr9Grwgd9WakmrGZBAin8yVX6YmfLC6O1KkrVwiJDrB3lP6VrlWRCMrlmBnjMlqwzFD_Bx3vqSmoKlWo9I9b5bvPgcFZY58EO2zARsBmLAjqtSZTdDB9dasohuPjXpDa9lOR.sO5oOhIQKC6NcHC3CIIuzA&state=5dc5b208-6093-4d1b-b9ed-c9d2091a306f&session_state=9984091c-6eb7-4395-a335-27aff1334a5f
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,703 [DEBUG] PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:106) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] checkCorsPreflight https://APP_HOST/keycloak/?code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..0-5C1AJAZrNXJwmZbt4I0Q.LET3bu8MVK6Uq58-j-yPC0WP_F01jskmm6WvyXqRRURlMiVIH9VV0fx6Cc3O4X0JFyTUiuESHUcfk2dyHOoL_z-IVVAAxTE-Eg2rphKjVT7OfWsoxuHZKFY9RkyEnr9Grwgd9WakmrGZBAin8yVX6YmfLC6O1KkrVwiJDrB3lP6VrlWRCMrlmBnjMlqwzFD_Bx3vqSmoKlWo9I9b5bvPgcFZY58EO2zARsBmLAjqtSZTdDB9dasohuPjXpDa9lOR.sO5oOhIQKC6NcHC3CIIuzA&state=5dc5b208-6093-4d1b-b9ed-c9d2091a306f&session_state=9984091c-6eb7-4395-a335-27aff1334a5f
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,767 [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache.process(RequestAuthCache.java:76) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Auth cache not set in the context
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,703 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:279) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] there was a code, resolving
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,704 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:325) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] checking state cookie for after code
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,704 [DEBUG] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.checkStateCookie(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:244) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ** reseting application state cookie
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,705 [DEBUG] ThreadSafeClientConnManager.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:239) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Get connection: {s}->https://KEYCLOAK_HOST:443, timeout = 0
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,706 [DEBUG] ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:347) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [{s}->https://KEYCLOAK_HOST:443] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 20
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,706 [DEBUG] ConnPoolByRoute.getFreeEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:496) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Getting free connection [{s}->https://KEYCLOAK_HOST:443][null]
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,707 [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:433) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Stale connection check
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,708 [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:435) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Stale connection detected
2019-01-11T12:03:21.70+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,708 [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:182) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Connection 0.0.0.0:47716<->11.217.32.122:443 closed
2019-01-11T12:03:21.71+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,709 [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:176) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Connecting to KEYCLOAK_HOST:443
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,767 [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:122) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CookieSpec selected: compatibility
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,768 [DEBUG] RequestProxyAuthentication.process(RequestProxyAuthentication.java:88) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,768 [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Attempt 1 to execute request
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,768 [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:276) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Sending request: POST /auth/realms/kums/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
2019-01-11T12:03:21.76+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,769 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "POST /auth/realms/kums/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,769 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "Authorization: Basic ...[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,770 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "Content-Length: 577[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,770 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,770 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "Host: KEYCLOAK_HOST[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,771 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,771 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,771 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:280) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> POST /auth/realms/kums/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,772 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:283) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> Authorization: Basic ...
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,772 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:283) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> Content-Length: 577
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,772 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:283) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,773 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:283) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> Host: KEYCLOAK_HOST
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,773 [DEBUG] headers.sendRequestHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:283) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,774 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:86) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  >> "grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..0-5C1AJAZrNXJwmZbt4I0Q.LET3bu8MVK6Uq58-j-yPC0WP_F01jskmm6WvyXqRRURlMiVIH9VV0fx6Cc3O4X0JFyTUiuESHUcfk2dyHOoL_z-IVVAAxTE-Eg2rphKjVT7OfWsoxuHZKFY9RkyEnr9Grwgd9WakmrGZBAin8yVX6YmfLC6O1KkrVwiJDrB3lP6VrlWRCMrlmBnjMlqwzFD_Bx3vqSmoKlWo9I9b5bvPgcFZY58EO2zARsBmLAjqtSZTdDB9dasohuPjXpDa9lOR.sO5oOhIQKC6NcHC3CIIuzA&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FAPP_HOST%2Fkeycloak%2F&client_session_state=FE94EAFFC87674ED70E0C1EC543CFBAE&client_session_host=dc36d0f9-10cf-4807-74e3-b2da"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,776 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,776 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,776 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,777 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,777 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,777 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Content-Length: 70[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,778 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 11:03:21 GMT[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,778 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:72) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "[\r][\n]"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,778 [DEBUG] DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:261) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,779 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:264) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,779 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Connection: keep-alive
2019-01-11T12:03:21.77+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,779 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Cache-Control: no-store
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,780 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Pragma: no-cache
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,780 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Content-Type: application/json
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,780 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Content-Length: 70
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,780 [DEBUG] headers.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:267) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] << Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 11:03:21 GMT
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,781 [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClient.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:511) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,781 [DEBUG] wire.wire(Wire.java:86) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]  << "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Incorrect redirect_uri"}"
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,782 [DEBUG] ThreadSafeClientConnManager.releaseConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:285) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Released connection is reusable.
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,782 [DEBUG] ConnPoolByRoute.freeEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:431) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Releasing connection [{s}->https://KEYCLOAK_HOST:443][null]
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,782 [DEBUG] ConnPoolByRoute.freeEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:457) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Pooling connection [{s}->https://KEYCLOAK_HOST:443][null]; keep alive indefinitely
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,782 [DEBUG] ConnPoolByRoute.notifyWaitingThread(ConnPoolByRoute.java:678) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,783 [ERROR] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:337) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] failed to turn code into token
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,783 [ERROR] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:338) [http-nio-8080-exec-2] status from server: 400
2019-01-11T12:03:21.78+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-01-11 12:03:21,783 [ERROR] OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:340) [http-nio-8080-exec-2]    {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Incorrect redirect_uri"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your client properly. 
Go to Keycloak to your client configuration
Set the allowed redirect url

See this post here
[keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352880/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I know. The login mask is working fine but the code-to-token request not.
The Problem is that I'm not able to look into the keycloak configuration. This is provided as a service from a different department.

Comment: I was having the same error message, but it was because I was accidentally double-encoding the redirect_uri value in the POST to the token endpoint. Other OpenID Connect IdPs haven't complained about this, but Keycloak does. 

However, looking at your logs above, that doesn't seem to be an issue for you.