# Can't see keycloak login form

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, keycloak, camunda

I'm trying to use Keycloak as SSO for Camunda and Spring app. I'm using this code:
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/springboot-keycloak-sso/spring-security-and-springboot-adapter

I've made only two changes to this project:

First: Changed dependency of camunda keycloak plugin to:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
   <artifactId>camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Second: Change of application properties (spring app is running 8081, keycloak 8080 for now):

```
keycloak:
  realm: Workflow
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  resource: camunda-identity-service
  ssl-required: none
  credentials.secret : f0fee400-1b19-4f41-a018-cdc5cc351b80

plugin.identity.keycloak:
  keycloakIssuerUrl: https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/Workflow
  keycloakAdminUrl: https://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/Workflow
  clientId: camunda-identity-service
  clientSecret: f0fee400-1b19-4f41-a018-cdc5cc351b80
  useUsernameAsCamundaUserId: true
  disableSSLCertificateValidation: true
```

After trying to get to spring app I'm redirected to login page but I'm getting "This connection has ben lost" in browser. I've enabled keycloak logs:

```
2021-01-26 11:44:38.686 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.k.a.s.management.HttpSessionManager    : Session created: EFE6D48E75B809FF544F1E051D8C18CD
2021-01-26 11:44:38.686 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] k.a.s.a.KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint : Redirecting to login URI /sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.695 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8081/sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:8081/sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8081/sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2021-01-26 11:44:38.697 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2021-01-26 11:44:38.701 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.a.s.token.SpringSecurityTokenStore   : Checking if org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator@4bfbad9a is cached
2021-01-26 11:44:38.702 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : there was no code
2021-01-26 11:44:38.702 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : redirecting to auth server
2021-01-26 11:44:38.703 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : callback uri: http://localhost:8081/sso/login
2021-01-26 11:44:38.704 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: NOT_ATTEMPTED
2021-01-26 11:44:38.704 DEBUG 19200 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : Sending redirect to login page: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/Workflow/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=camunda-identity-service&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=a1e3b3be-422f-48e4-98a4-262817ff4349&login=true&scope=openid
```

What am I'm doing wrong that I can't see login page?

EDIT 1:

I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and now I'm redirected to form but getting this message: *Invalid parameter: redirect_uri* . To solve this problem I used this thread -> [keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352880/keycloak-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri)