# keycloak 18 + React logout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I'm using **keycloak-react/web** and **keycloak-js** packages in my React project. This is what I have in my keycloak.js

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const host = window.location.host

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  url: `http://localhost:8080/auth`,
  realm: 'demo',
  clientId: 'demo',
})

export default keycloak
```

And this is how I logout the sso-logged-in user

```
{
  !!keycloak.authenticated && (
    <li>
      <a href='/#' onClick={() => keycloak.logout()}>Logout</a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

This used to work fine till I switched to keycloak v18.x.x Quarkus. Now, it doesn't even logout the user, let along redirect them to the homepage. What I understand from their documentation, which is stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72011979), is that they've changed the mechanism to logout. But what I don't understand is how and where do I use this `post_logout_redirect_uri`

**Update:** I updated the JavaScript adapter (keycloak-js) to v19.0.1 which at least logs-out the user now but still haven't figured out how to redirect back to the login page

Answer (score 1):

Update the JavaScript adapter (keycloak-js) to V19.0.1 as mentioned in the question and then make your code like this:

```
{
  !!keycloak.authenticated && (
    <li>
      <a href='/#' onClick={() => keycloak.logout({ redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/' })}>Logout</a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!