# Keycloak 20.0.3 logout not working in react app (invalid redirect url)

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to authenticate my react app using keycloak. The app is not able to successfully logout. I have setup the admin console to contain the post logout redirect url to be `http://localhost:7171`. The URL that shows on clicking logout button

`http://localhost:8080/realms/hype/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id=hypeclient&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7171%2F&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJZRHVhc0pTT0dIOUh2ZnRvZGNhRktmRkxuOEZuWmkzSVN3eVBQenlzazFVIn0.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.TFCh-dPE4h8HKpAapNv4socR7uAsKDnuVpqLiaZCguu1Vyztn_sUkrbaqFKJDeoIZv3XDzBDM5MezMvyRRkmiRIQTIbiTlYGgcNA5UkcwbeKioaowCWqYqyjG7A3D0lKNjf0MAF6PmWVrPJVbm8hYtQMVDHwWQ2vFTShnmMRJ2iTf4IeT1DDLANrLh3tMXeYMF2f9ZmvtNS72O-BICkD4uXPSyMiqnDgj_52UAdkEaLgkuv31TAYDAeVef-Rly8n7K5LG1MWytB2_-WrhwXwfxjymc9RH55Iy-1tvLUFceigO7XwQzffZYK5uJ9PXkbg3hlkr6QLVSXsiu8RYKQu9w`

My Setup including the version looks like

```
Keycloak 20.0.3
Keycloak.js 20.0.3 via npm
react 18.2
```

App.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import keycloak from "./Keycloak";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import WelcomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
import SecuredPage from "./pages/Securedpage";
import PrivateRoute from "./helpers/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
 return (
   <div>
     <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
       <Nav />
       <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route exact path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
           <Route path="/secured"
             element={<PrivateRoute>
                 <SecuredPage />
               </PrivateRoute>}/>
         </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
     </ReactKeycloakProvider>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Nav.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";

const Nav = () => {
 const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();

 function loginHelper(){
   console.log("login clicked");
   keycloak.login();
 };

 function logoutHelper(){
   console.log("login clicked");
   keycloak.logout();
 };


 return (
   <div>
     <div className="top-0 w-full flex flex-wrap">
       <section className="x-auto">
         <nav className="flex justify-between bg-gray-200 text-blue-800 w-screen">
           <div className="px-5 xl:px-12 py-6 flex w-full items-center">
             <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold font-heading">
               Keycloak React AUTH.
             </h1>
             <ul className="hidden md:flex px-4 mx-auto font-semibold font-heading space-x-12">
               <li>
                 <a className="hover:text-blue-800" href="/">
                   Home
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a className="hover:text-blue-800" href="/secured">
                   Secured Page
                 </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
             <div className="hidden xl:flex items-center space-x-5">
               <div className="hover:text-gray-200">
                 {!keycloak.authenticated && (
                   <button
                     type="button"
                     className="text-blue-800"
                     onClick={() => loginHelper()}
                   >
                     Login
                   </button>
                 )}

                 {!!keycloak.authenticated && (
                   <button
                     type="button"
                     className="text-blue-800"
                     onClick={() => logoutHelper()}
                   >
                     Logout ({keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username})
                   </button>
                 )}
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </nav>
       </section>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Nav;
```

Keycloak.JS

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
 url: "http://localhost:8080",
 realm: "hype",
 clientId: "hypeclient",
});

export default keycloak;
```

PrivateRoute.JS

```
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
 const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

 const isLoggedIn = keycloak.authenticated;
 console.log("checking auth access " + isLoggedIn);
 return isLoggedIn ? children : null;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I have tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73190437/keycloak-18-react-logout-issue) but it does not work. Admin console looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

- valid post logout urls to `+`
- valid redirect urls to `http://localhost:7171*`