# How can know the running process's config file location?

Tags: macos, apache

I can find the apache process in my Mac by:

```
$ ps -ef | grep httpd
  0    96     1   0 五10上午 ??         0:03.21 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 70   256    96   0 五10上午 ??         0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 70  4016    96   0 五03下午 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 70  4017    96   0 五03下午 ??         0:00.04 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 70  4018    96   0 五03下午 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
501 11243 10710   0 11:40上午 ttys002    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

you see there is `/usr/sbin/httpd` running, but how can I know the config file of `/usr/sbin/httpd`? because there are several apache installed in my Mac.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/lost-httpd-conf-file-located-apache

Answer (score 0):

From this [document](https://www.techtransit.org/find-apache-httpd-conf-configuration-file-on-linux-server/):

you can use:

```
$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```