# Issue while trying to point to new domain

Tags: php, dns

I have 2 cpanels. Both have a domain and a server. Code files and database are same on both side. I am told point old domain to new domain.

I wrote below code in index file and all public files which are not password protected in old server.

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com"); 
?>
```

Everything works fine so far.

**Issue details**

I renamed index file in old server as it is not password protected and then tried to access the renamed file.

I got Access Forbidden error as the file was not found on old domain.

Can you please suggest if there is any way that old domain points to new domain even after I stop using the services in old cpanel?

Comment: You need to make the old domain a parked domain for the new domain

Comment: better to use an htaccess rewrite rule than adding a redirect in index files

Comment: I suggest adding cpanel tag

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION 1 using cPanel

cPanel has an interface called "Assign Domain" it has 4 steps

*(note that your cPanel flavor could be different from this one according to your host, however the steps should be almost the same )*

### step 1 (Enter Domain):

Here cPanel will try to resolve the domain you enterted (olddomain.com) and detect it's current DNS server

[image]

### step 2 (Verify Ownership):

Here you are going to verify your ownership of the (olddomain.com).

cPanel detected that olddomain.com is currently resolved by NS1.SMARTNAME.COM .

I use the DNS method to completely leave my old server, no traffic at all to old server. it's  also handy if you registered your domain with a company like godaddy and your server and host is on another company.

[image]

### step 3 (Choose Addon vs. Parked):

Here you are going to chose Parked domain for your case

[image]

### step 4 (Choose Addon Directory and Sub-domain):

This step is available only for addon domains in which you chose the public_directory of the new adddomain and the subdomain

### OPTION 2 using 1 frontController PHP file and rewrite rule(thanks for @tim in comments)

add a rewrite rule in your httpd.conf file that sends every request to your frontController PHP file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/frontController.SE.php"
RewriteRule .* /frontController.SE.php [L]
```

and create a new PHP file called `frontController.SE.php`

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com");
exit; 
?>
```

that is better than coping the same code in all of your public files

Comment: Where can I search for httpd.config?

Comment: There is another issue. Let's say,  the default file(index.php)  is renamed or removed. Then it gives an error access forbidden because the file is not found. I tested this issue on other files also. Same issue occurs.

Comment: @Pankaj httpd.conf is the Apache configuration file, your webserver is Apache, right ?

Comment: @Pankaj Access forbidden is different from file not found, do you get 404 error in your browser when you request `index.php` ?

Comment: My server is shared hosting. There is no root access. So, where should I find the httpd.conf file?

Comment: Error 403. Error Details:

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: @Pankaj Ask your host if they allow you to modify the Apache configuration file(httpd.conf), if not then you should go to .htaccess files. check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/lost-httpd-conf-file-located-apache) for the location of `httpd.conf` file

Comment: This happens when I rename the index file to test the permanent redirect to make sure if it will still work after removing the file. I have to stop the services from old cpanel. So, this does not seems safe to stop using the services from old cpanel.

The old cpanel does not allow to modify the httpd.conf as there is no root access.

Comment: @Pankaj Aha, now I understand your problem, you renamed `index.php` which is the default file to request if you requested the directory without specific file, for example , you request `mydomain/` , the webserver will try to find `index.php` or `index.html` in that directory, if it didn't find it, it will give this error that tells you you don't have the permission to the directory itself, you should keep your name as `index.php`, why do you want to change it ?

Comment: Actually, we have to stop using the services from old cpanel and we want to shut down the old cpanel completely. That's why I thought to test the permanent redirect by doing this. I was testing a case when the old panel i shut down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198211/discussion-between-pankaj-and-accountant-).